# Browser scrollbar is nowhere to be found?

Tags: php, html, css, browser

Okay basically for some reason, I barely noticed that when I load up my project the scrollbar is missing on all browsers, which is weird, i can force scroll by clicking down on the little mouse ball on my mouse. Although on internet explore that doesn't work at all.

I tried to retrace my steps after modifying my code to see what could have gone, but since i barely realized it, not very sure when it occurred. Thats why I can not provide a problematic code.

I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look at it for me.

Removed link Because answer is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overflow:hidden on your html. If you change it to scroll, the scroll bar appears.

If you are wanting to stop horizontal scrolling, use overflow-x:hidden

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly, not sure if I can choose two answers, because DevZer0 also answered correctly, if i can only choose one, it will be as you were first. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

your body has the following css.

```
#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
```

This is causing the scroll bars to be hidden;